# How can I declare a variable nil until I need it?

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite.swift

Am just starting to use SQLite in Swift and am running into a declaration problem. I would like to wrap everything in one class that I can then call methods on.

My problem is I don't know how to declare db so that when I do call Connect, it can be filled in an always be available while the class exists. I could call connect at the init, but I don't want to call Connect until I need it. When I code it as below I get the following error:

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

```
class MySQL {
    var db : Connection
    var dbPath : String
    
    init() {
        dbPath = getDocumentsDirectory().absoluteString + "db.sqlite3"
    }
    
    func open(){
        do{
            db = try Connection(dbPath)}
        catch{}

        let users = Table("users")
        print(users)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could call connect at the init, but I don't want to call Connect until I need it.

Absolutely right! Don't do anything like that in `init`.

Just rewrite your declaration to make the Connection `nil`, precisely as you suggested:

```
class MySQL {
    var db : Connection? = nil
    var dbPath : String
    
    init() {
        dbPath = getDocumentsDirectory().absoluteString + "db.sqlite3"
    }
    
    func open(){
        do{
            db = try Connection(dbPath)}
        catch{}

        let users = Table("users")
        print(users)
    }
}
```

The consequence is that whenever you talk to `self.db` from now on, except in order set it, you will have to check whether it is `nil`. You can use Optional chaining to do that painlessly. You could avoid that by declaring `db` as `Connection!` instead of `Connection?` but that risks a later crash and I can't recommend it.

Comment: I should add: there are a lot of great SQLite front end libraries and you could save yourself a lot of work by just using one.

Comment: Thank you, this was it. I was trying nil, but without the ?.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use lazy property.

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value isn’t calculated until the first time it’s used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

```
class MySQL {
    lazy var db : Connection = {
        // Make initialisation here 
    }()
    var dbPath : String

    ...
}
```

More information you can read from [official docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

Comment: Whenever I use this i get get an error `Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Connection'`. Have you tested the code?

Comment: @MrinmoyMk Looks like you don't complete the return statement in the closure. If the closure is empty, you will see this error. Probably, this is the reason.